# Unexpected character (at character 2) dart flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Getting stored data on my flutter hive makes me fall into this error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Unexpected character (at character 2)
{id: 2, network: MTN, discount: 2, logo: mtncard.png}
 ^
```

Here is my class:

```dart
class Provider {
  Provider({
    required this.id,
    required this.network,
    required this.discount,
    required this.logo,
  });
  final String id;
  final String network;
  final int discount;
  final String logo;

  factory Provider.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final id = data['id'] as String;
    final network = data['network'] as String;
    final discount = int.parse(data['discount']);
    final logo = data['logo'] as String;
    return Provider(
      id: id,
      network: network,
      discount: discount,
      logo: logo,
      );
  }
}
```

and here is my functions:

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> LoadData() async {
  final name = await Hive.box<dynamic>('my_db');
  final result = name.values.toList();
  print(result);
  //print result is gotten perfectly from hive box
  return name.values.toList();
}
```

This my future builder:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
  future: LoadData(),
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('loading'),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount:
            snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder:
            (BuildContext context,
                int index) {
          // Decoding the string to Map
          final Map<String, dynamic>
              decodedData =
              jsonDecode(snapshot
                  .data[index]);

          // Mapping the Map to Provider object
          final itemData =
              Provider.fromJson(
                  decodedData);

          return ListTile(
            title: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment:
                  CrossAxisAlignment
                      .center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment:
                      MainAxisAlignment
                          .spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      itemData
                        .discount
                            .toString(),
                      style:
                          const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight:
                            FontWeight
                                .bold,
                        fontSize:
                            20,
                        color: Colors
                            .green,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons
                          .more_horiz,
                      color: Colors
                          .blue,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
}),
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: Could you please format the code in your question? It is really hard to read

Comment: Also, replace [hive] with [flutter-hive]. They aren't the same tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the JSON decoding, which you can fix by encoding the JSON string first with the `jsonEncode` function.

So, your code would look like this:

```
// Decoding the string to Map
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData =
  jsonDecode(jsonEncode(snapshot.data[index]));
```

Refer to the problem and the solution here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32841#issuecomment-514454946

Comment: oh thanks for your option but this `code` got into i deeper error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` could chrck were this error is??  thanks @Dhafin

Comment: Could you show me what the runtime type of that `snapshot.data[index]` is? Maybe you could do `print(snapshot.data[index].runtimeType)` in the line before `decodedData` @MondayPGodstime

Comment: it runtype is just `String` @Dhafin

Comment: Can you track which line gave you the error? Did the execution passed this line: `final itemData = Provider.fromJson(decodedData);`?

Comment: oh my God am really new in dart is there any method i can use to verify if the execution actualy pass? maybe a `code` example @Dhafin

Comment: You can use `print`. Just put some `print` functions on different part of the code, and then see the output in Debug Console or terminal @MondayPGodstime

Comment: i dont have idea on how to go about that  will be nice if you could show me part to place the print function with my existing code in question body above thanks @Dhafin

Comment: i could not fined a possible place to place a print to it